# "ORA-00600 Internal error" code when creating an OLAP cube

Tags: oracle

I'm creating an OLAP cube and I've a problem.

I'm using Oracle DB 12c and AWM 12.2 to create the cube. When I use "Maintain Cube" and load the data, I recieve an `ORA-00600: Internal error code` error.

The following is the log for the error:

```
2020-05-28T15:52:05.774911+02:00
ORCLPDB(3):ERROR: Unable to normalize symbol name for the following short stack (at offset 286):
dbgexProcessError()+398<-dbgePostErrorKGE()+2191<-dbkePostKGE_kgsf()+90<-kgeadse()+457<-kgerinv_internal()+86<-kgerinv()+63<-kgesinv()+43<-ksesin()+143<-xsTermIVX()+650<-xssqlEndAttrCB()+145<-xsldLoadDone()+216<-xsldInternalLoadQry()+3809<-xsldLoadDimQry()+2232<-xsoqLoadDimQry()+889<-?r12LoadDim@TxsOqStdFormCommand@@SAXPEAVTxsOqMdmPrimaryDimension@@PEAVTxsOqMdmDimensionLevel@@AEBVxswstring@@FW4ExsOqDimensionLoadPhase@@PEAV?$std_vector@PEAVTxsOqMdmAttributeMa()<-?runSQL@TxsOqLoadCommandProcessorDimensionContext@@QEAAXW4ExsOqDimensionLoadPhase@@PEAVTxsOqLoadCommandDimensionInfo@@AEAV?$std_vector@PEAVTxsOqMdmHierarchy@@@@PEAVTxsOqMdmBaseA()<-?loadAll@TxsOqLoadCommandProcessorDimensionContext@@QEAAXW4ExsOqDimensionLoadPhase@@AEBVxswstring@@PEAVTxsOqMdmBaseAttribute@@PEBUkscn@@@Z()+2459<-?loadDimension@TxsOqLoadCommandProcessor@@AEAAXPEBUkscn@@@Z()+531<-?run@TxsOqLoadCommandProcessor@@UEAAXXZ()+306<-?runCommand@TxsOqBuildCommandProcessor@@QEAAXXZ()+365<-?runNextCommand@TxsOqBuildItemProcessor@@QEAAFXZ()+97<-?runNextCommand@TxsOqBuildProcessor@@QEAAXXZ()+114<-?performNextAction@TxsOqBuildProcessor@@QEAAFXZ()+96<-?nextAction@TxsOqBuildProcessor@@QEAAFXZ()+63<-?performActions@TxsOqBuildProcessor@@QEAAXFPEAI0PEAUxsoqSCN@@@Z()+110<-?finishBuild@TxsOqBuildProcessor@@QEAAXFPEAI0PEAUxsoqSCN@@@Z()+178<-?execute@TxsOqBuildProcessor@@QEAAXAEBVxswstring@@PEAI@Z()+1898<-?executeBuild@TxsOqBuildProcessor@@SAXPEAVTxsOqConnection@@AEBVxswstring@@1IPEAIF11H1HPEAUxsoqSCN@@AEAVxsxmlwstring@@@Z()+493<-?executeBuild@TxsOqConnection@@QEAAXAEBVxswstring@@AEAVxsxmlwstring@@@Z()+811<-?generic@TxsOqConnection@@UEAAXPEBEPEBGAEAPEAG@Z()+1222<-?internal_cDataProvider_generic_so@@YAXPEAUOCIExtProcContext@@PEAUxsoqStreamContext@@@Z()+181<-xsoqStreamCallout()+1237<-eDataProvider_generic()+98<-spefcmpa()+323<-spefmccallstd()+303<-pextproc()+102<-peftrusted()+132<-psdexsp()+467<-kxe_push_env_internal_pp_()+786<-kkx_push_env_for_ICD_for_new_session()+151<-psdextp()+5
    Errors in file C:\USERS\USER\ORACLESUITE\ORACLEDB\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4640.trc  (incident=64340) (PDBNAME=ORCLPDB):
    ORA-00600: codice di errore interno, argomenti: [xsTermIVX invalid position], [REVIEW_AW!DIM_BUSINESS_LEVELREL], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
    ORCLPDB(3):Incident details in: C:\USERS\USER\ORACLESUITE\ORACLEDB\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_64340\orcl_ora_4640_i64340.trc
```

Can you help me solve this problem?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

By definition, ora-0600 is an "unhandled exception" (aka, "you hit a bug").  It will require Oracle Support to sort it out, and that requires a paid support contract.  If you already have that, When you log on to MOS, there is an 'ora-600 lookup tool' that will produce documents on known issues, based on the sub-codes that came with the ora-600.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, but I was hoping there was some sort of fix.